# Opening in a partition wall for 83-cm door

Tags: doors, partition

I was told that 83-cm door width is de-facto standard in France. What should be the opening size in the partition wall for that door size?

I found one nice door which unfortunately I had to return due to many factory errors. For that particular door model the required opening was **210x93.5**. Can I use this size in general, or it largely depends on the door model?

Comment: Bricomarche or Leroy Merlin will hold stock of pretty much all you need. Have you asked them?

Comment: @Tim I've bought "premium door" in Leroy Merlin, and they were all crap. The right-angle joints on the door frame were skewed etc. Another problem is that I have two load-bearing walls that are 15 cm wide, so I'm looking for a door frame that also supports wider walls. That is actually not a problem, there is a simple door frame system to support this, but they are not offered in Leroy Merlin. I will check with Bricomarche, thanks!! Since I will have to build partition walls before choosing doors, my main question still remains: **how much opening should I make in the partition wall?**

Comment: Can use any size of door you want/like.  Usually it is the width of the door plus a few mm, plus the size of the door frame(might come with door), a few mm/cm for fitting, and that should give the rough opening in the wall.  Is the wall just a partition or is it close to the centre of the house and a load bearing wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

830mm for the door 3 each side, above and below for the gaps 19 each side (and above) for the jambs. 5 to 15 extra each side for adjustment wedges.

So if my arithmetic is correct your hole in the framing should be 885 to 905 mm wide and height of door + 35 to 45  tall.

Check the thickness of the wood you'll be using for jambs. 19mm is what we use here in NZ and in Australia, and basically what they use in USA, but it might be different over there.